Get numeric values of Decimal data types defined in schema
I've defined the following Prisma schema:
model aikon_articulo {
  aik_ar_codigo           String @db.VarChar(24) @id
  aik_ar_descri           String? @db.VarChar(200)
  aik_ar_memo             String? @db.VarChar(4000)
  aik_re1_codigo          String? @db.VarChar(5)
  aik_re2_codigo          String? @db.VarChar(5)
  aik_ar_alto             Float?
  aik_ar_ancho            Float?
  aik_ar_profundo         Float?
  aik_ar_color            String? @db.VarChar(20)
  aik_ar_peso             Float?
  aik_ar_descria          String? @db.VarChar(200)
  aik_ar_fechamodif       DateTime?
  aik_ar_mesesgarantia    Float?
  aik_ar_cosnet           Decimal? @db.Decimal(15,2)
  aik_ap_utilidad         Decimal? @db.Decimal(6, 2)
  aik_impuesto_interno    Decimal? @db.Decimal(6, 2)
  aik_iva_porcen          Decimal? @db.Decimal(6, 2)
  aik_stock_total         Int? @db.UnsignedSmallInt
  aik_ap_precio_iva       Decimal? @db.Decimal(15,2)
}

When I run  prisma.aikon_articulo.findMany() I get as a String the values of fields that were defined as Decimal. I know that under the hood Prisma is using decimal.js library.
I'd like to get them as numeric values and not strings, just like the database stores it. Take the example of aik_ar_cosnet: SQL stores the numeric value 109457.00, but Prisma library returns "109457" string. I'd like that Prisma returns the same value the database does.
Aside for that, I'm defining Decimal for those values that are used for currency. I don't know if this Prisma data type is correct to use in this situation. Could I use another Prisma datatype?
